# Uncertainty Principle Violations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, bells-inequality

I’m learning about Bells Inequality Experiment and have a question because the instructor in the video I am watching simply passed over something I found jarring.

Ok, you have your entangled pairs of electrons with measurable spin on the x,y,and z direction. Alice measures x as positive, yells to Bob her results, and Bob measures his z as positive. So, both of them would now seem to know their particles x and z spin, but apparently this violates the Uncertainty principle.

What are the consequences of this? Is this to say that now, should Bob measure his particle in the x direction, he might end up with it going in the positive direction as well? Is the particle suddenly “scrambled” into either direction now that Bob might potentially know the full story? Does the measurement in one direction always scramble the direction in the other axis?

If so, then I think I finally understand what’s so odd about quantum physics.

Comment: Can you explain what the violation is specifically?

Comment: The video I was watching made it sounds like the violation was that we could know the x and z spin of each particle because we know 1 of each per particle, and since they are entangled, they should therefore have the opposite values of each other and provide us the full picture. So if we know particle 1 has x + and particle 2 has z - , we know 1 has x+, z+; 2 has x-, z-. Is this a violation of the uncertainty principle, as we now know the spin in both directions for both particles?

Comment: @Jc5785a : As shown in a few simple steps in [EPR Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPR_paradox#Mathematical_formulation) the outcome of the measurement that Bob performs is uniformly random. In particular Bob cannot conclude from that outcome what spin in the $z$ direction Alice's particle 'has'.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Alice knows the outcome of her measuring X on her electron. Bob the outcome of him measuring Z on his electron. Neither knows the value of both X and Z on a specific electron, which would be an "uncertainty principle violation". What Alice tells Bob doesn't have any effect on this: when he measures on Z he collapses his state in the corresponding basis, so he won't get the same outcome as Alice if he were to measure X again, so he doesn't "know both X and Z" on his electron. This also doesn't really have anything to do with Bell's inequalities

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no problem here. If Alice measure spin z after spin x it will not be the same as Bob.In this case the entanglement is broke and is not sure that spin z of alice is the same of Bob. Think that problem in a ensemble context, let s suppose that you have a lot o electrons pairs, and alice measure spin x and after spin z. The values of spin z will be 50% up and 50% down, in disagreement with bob. Furthermore, Alice only will knows the spin z when she measure that.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. Just simply : can you not know the x and z direction of each particle by “combining” your knowledge of each particle? Or, because you know Alice measured x+ (and therefore bobs particle must be x-), does that terminate the correlation in all other directions? So now if Bob does measure the z direction and gets z-, we can’t know that Bob has x-, z-; Alice has x+, z+ because of the uncertainty principle. Is this true? Because that makes no logical sense to me at all.